# Running simple PySpark examples fails

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We're beggining with Spark (using PySpark) and we're facing problems in a VMware ESX 5.5 evironment with Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS virtual machines with Java version "1.8.0_45".

Running a simple `sc.parallelize(['2', '4']).collect()` results in this:

```
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <stdin>:1
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at <stdin>:1) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(collect at <stdin>:1)
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:396), which has no missing parents
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at <stdin>:1) failed in Unknown s
15/07/28 10:11:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at <stdin>:1, took 0,058933 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 745, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/opt/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:68)
org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:60)
org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1289)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:874)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Found this issue regarding the same behavior: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9089

Any idea of what's happening? Or what can we try?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the issue:

> We've faced this same problem and after digging and having a lot of
>   luck we've found the origin of the issue.
>
> It is caused because snappy-java extracts the native library to
>   java.io.tempdir (/tmp by default) and sets the executable flag to the
>   extracted file. If you are mounting /tmp with the "noexec" option,
>   snappy-java won't be able to set the executable flag and will raise an
>   exception. See the SnappyLoader.java code.
>
> We've fixed the issue by not using the option "noexec" when mounting
>   /tmp.
>
> Sean Owen If you want to reproduce the issue, mount /tmp with "noexec"
>   option or set the java.io.tempdir to a directory mounted with
>   "noexec".
>
> Maybe it would be better that Spark sets the property
>   org.xerial.snappy.tempdir to the value of spark.local.dir, but nothing
>   prevents that spark.local.dir may be mounted as "noexec" also.

Removing `noexec` from the `/tmp` mountpoint fixed this issue.